# How can I remove dark stains from laminate flooring?

Tags: laminate, stain

[image: Flooring with dark staining]

This is laminate flooring. Not planks. No idea what the stain is at all!

Any suggestions on how to get it out or what it is?

Response to answers below:
I have not tried steam cleaning. I heard water and laminate floors don't do well together?

Perfect wording Jack, I've been trying to explain this flooring for awhile, because it's not individual planks, it's all one piece, with a picture of wood on top. I do not know what the core is though.

It is mostly infront of the dish washer with a small dot over by the fridge and one dot to the side of the stove. There is also one near the trim on the wall which is no where near a water source (except the bathroom on the other side of the wall).

I have tried magic eraser in case it was a stain, and it did nothing. I have also tried acetone nail polish remover on a portion that was most hidden, and again nothing happened.

I live in apartments, and the manager had one of thier friends come "look" at it. He was saying it looked like I had split something which then stained the floor.(which doesn't make since for all the locations). I have been home while a whole dish washer cycle goes through and have not seen any sitting water. Would water even do this?[image]

Comment: have you tried steam cleaning? i swear it fixes almost everything. it looks like a sugary or greasy liquid that dried and accumulated dirt from feet.

Comment: If that is typical laminate flooring with man made surface that has a picture of wood on it and the core is MDF, do not steam it. It will penetrate at the joints and swell the floor where it does. If it has a real wood surface, still be careful steaming a laminate/ floating floor.

Comment: Is it only in front of the fridge?

Comment: *it's all one piece, with a picture of wood on top.* That sounds more like sheet vinyl to me. I suppose it's possible that the stain is mold/mildew coming through from underneath. Is this laid on a concrete floor? Are you able to lift the edge near any of these stains to see the underside?

Comment: If this actually was vinyl flooring and not laminate, please edit your question to reflect this.

Comment: This looks like you've got water damage with water coming through the seam in the floorboard.  Could the dishwasher have leaked?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering, the vinyl floor was installed incorrectly and those stains are pieces of the old vinyl underneath saturated in the wrong kind of glue/epoxy . We got our floors replaced, and they look great. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Please [merge your accounts](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so that you can participate on this site more fully :)